# Found conflicting getters for name:Database Exception

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn;
    private EditText et1,et2,et3;
    DatabaseReference dr;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    DatabaseError error;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        et3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        class User{
            String name,email,password;
            User()
            {}
            User(String name,String email,String password)
            {
                this.name=name;
                this.email=email;
                this.password=password;
            }
        }
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = et1.getText().toString();
                String email = et2.getText().toString();
                String password = et3.getText().toString();
                User user = new User(name,email,password);
                dr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Profile-Detailed");
                String id = dr.push().getKey();
                dr.child(id).setValue(user);
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read app title value.", error.toException());
            }


        });
    }
}
```

It should save user data to database

```
DatabaseException:Found conflicting getters for name:isChaingingConfigurations.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack trace refers to isChangingConfigurations, which is the name of a method of Activity. This probably indicates that you have declared class User as an inner class of an activity. When Firebase serializes User it also tries to serialize the enclosing Activity class and fails.

Move the declaration of User to package level or change the declaration to make it a static inner class: public static class User.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably giving the wrong path to the FirebaseDatabase.

```
dr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Profile-Detailed");
```

Try with null path and or empty path in firebase real-time database or it will create automatically it-self.

```
dr.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

With this above line-of-code
you will add new attribute to `sub 0` index in firebase database.